# spring applicationConfig beans node

Tags: spring, spring-security, configuration-files

In the spring configuration file `applicationConfig.xml`, the root node is `beans`. 
But it doesn't contain only beans. In fact, security configuration requires an `http` element. 
My question is: while `http` is not (seems to me not to be) a `bean`, is it "bean like" in the sense that it determines the creation of a service, or refers to a running service (say the http listener for the application)?

PS. In "Spring Security Reference documentation" 3.1.0-DRAFT at 2.1.1:

> "Web/HTTP Security (...) Sets up the filters and related ***service beans*** used to apply the framework authentication mechanisms ..."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything in a Spring config is just setting up beans. You could--and in fact used to be forced to--set up all the beans yourself, but along about Spring 2.0, the framework added a nifty feature that they called ["Extensible XML Authoring"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html), which gives other people/projects a way to define their own, custom XML syntax that gets translated into Spring beans at startup via a [NamespaceHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandler.html).